# Segmentation fault when comparing an object to NULL which should equal NULL?

Tags: c++

I'm having a little trouble with a critical function in my program, I've put bug testing lines everywhere and singled it down to a single `if` statement"

```
template <typename Item>
bool BTNode<Item>::isNull(string leftOrRight)
{
    std::cout<<"Is NULL test outer."<<endl;
    bool returnNullTest = true;
    if (leftOrRight == "left")
    {
        std::cout<<"Is NULL test inner 1."<<endl;
        if (left != NULL)
        {
            returnNullTest = false;
        }
    }
    else if (leftOrRight == "right") //.c_str()
    {
        std::cout<<"Is NULL test inner 2."<<endl;
        if (right != NULL)
        {
            returnNullTest = false;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"NULL TEST FINISHED."<<endl;
    return returnNullTest;
}
```

this is the output:

```
Is NULL test outer.
Is NULL test inner 2.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

this is the definition of 'left' and 'right':

```
BTNode<Item>* left;
BTNode<Item>* right;
```

in the constructors for BTNode 'left' and 'right' are defined as:

```
left = NULL;
right = NULL;
```

does anyone have an idea as to where i'm going wrong with this, i've tried the line

```
if (left == NULL)
```

and

```
if (right == NULL)
```

with the Boolean switched around but I got the same error.

this is 'BTNode.h'

```
#ifndef matt_BTNode
#define matt_BTNode
#include <cstdlib>
namespace mattassign3{
template <typename Item>
class BTNode
{
    private:
    Item* data;
    BTNode<Item>* left;
    BTNode<Item>* right;

    public:
    BTNode();
    BTNode(Item* startingData);
    ~BTNode();
    BTNode<Item>* getLeft();
    BTNode<Item>* getRight();
    Item* getData();
    bool isNull(string leftOrRight);
    void setLeft(BTNode<Item>* leftToSet);
    void setRight(BTNode<Item>* rightToSet);
    void printInclData();
    float comparableNumber();
    string comparableString();
};
}
#include "BTNode.template"
#endif
```

Comment: What is the type of `BTNode`?

Comment: As an aside, you can do the check if the pointer is NOT `NULL` like: `if(left)`.

Comment: My spidey sense tells me the crash occurs *after* this function returns; you just don't get to see the output of the last `cout` statement printed for reasons which are not important to this discussion. Now would be a good time to learn how to use a debugger: google for **gdb**.

Comment: Alternatively to what @Nik says, the (actual) problem could have happened _before_. If you have incurred in undefined behaviour due to a previous illegal operation, maybe your reading access to `right` (whatever that is) is illegal, even to compare it against null.

Comment: i have other tests to check if the program exits (it doesn't)

Comment: there are NULL pointers, but in other parts of the program i'm checking if a pointer is null with no problems

Comment: i'll edit in the .h file for BTNode

Comment: remove using namespace std; first and add std:: to the appropriate variables. I think right and left might not be what you think, they can come from the standard library. This is why using namespace is evil. Hope it helps!

Comment: @MatthewMuller Again, at _this_ point you might have incurred in undefined behaviour due to an illegal operation. I suggest using design by contract and concentrating in the operations _before_ the crash to see if something is going wrong.

Comment: I see way too many pointer signs in your code, which makes my suspicions stronger. You may be already in an illegal BTNode<Item>*, i.e. your this is illegal, when you do this check. This is why you crash when you access `right`. The bug is elsewhere in your code. Again, make a heavy use of detailed debugging and design by contract. Add assertions to check that everything is going on as expected.

Comment: @DanielDaranas at this part of my program i have already constructed a tree from the nodes and whatnot, it also prints correctly, my problem is literally only appearing here

i have error checks all throughout the program prior to this, i've tried my best to isolate my problem to this spot before coming here

Comment: @DanielDaranas 'right' functions properly when the class is used in different areas of the code.

Comment: well, if you run this as a standalone function theres no problem, it must be somewhere else in your code

Comment: @MatthewMuller If the problem cannot be reproduced in every call to isNull, you clearly haven't isolated it correctly. I have provided my diagnostic, now it is your turn to debug your code.

Comment: I don't think that that *is* `BTNode.h` (hint: it says `#include "BTNode."`)

Comment: @MatthewMuller This is not a discussion forum. I have no need to convince you that you have a bug elsewhere in your code. I'm just saying it. You are free to not believe it and keep looking at the body of `isNull` for a few more hours.

Comment: @DanielDaranas that's just it, this problem appeared when i was comparing to NULL in another part of the code in a different class, i made this function in BTNode to try and fix the problem but it still exists and i'm not sure why, do you think it has something to do with the BTNode itself?

Comment: @MatthewMuller Daniel and Serve are spot on - the bug is elsewhere.

Comment: @MatthewMuller As I said before, and as the answer says, most likely **this** is an invalid pointer. You have inadvertently incurred in undefined behaviour. **Stop thinking about null pointers.**. Some pointer to BTNode has become **invalid** (not null), due to some previous illegal operation. Now when you are inside isNull, it is too late. The object you are in is already illegal. Debug your code previous to the point where you observe the error. Use design by contract for that: create an invariant of BTNode, and check it after each relevant operation.

Comment: In particular, and just as an example: **Do your two constructors initialize left and right correctly?** Please don't tell me that BTNode() doesn't initialize them.

Comment: left and right weren't being initialized before (it somehow was still working) but the error didn't disappear once they were initialized properly, i'm checking to see where it breaks now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely `this` is an invalid pointer. The function crashed the first time a member of `this` was accessed. Try printing `this` along with the first message.

Comment: @kfsone Could be anything, including calling a member function on a `left` or `right` link which was set to null.

Comment: i've tested the BTNode that goes through and this is right, i've managed to break it along the way.

is there any common mistakes that could cause this?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you crash when accessing "right" is a symptom of a bug higher in your call stack. Specifically, prior to arriving at this point in your program you must have done something like, e.g.

```
BNode* node = something->getRight();
node->isNull();
```

You need to remind yourself that in your `isNull` function `right` and `left` are member variables. Their locations in memory are relative to the *instance* of BNode they belong to, they are not just some local variables (this is another good reason why many programmers choose to distinguish member variables with a prefix like "m_", e.g. "m_left", "m_right").

If the "BNode*" pointer you are calling "isNull" against is bad, then it helps to remember that when you say

```
if(left != NULL)
```

you are accessing *(this + 4 bytes). You're "getting away" with access "left", but "right" is unfortunately on the other side of some kind of memory boundary that results in your crash.

Make sure: Your constructors assign default values to these pointers, that you check return values from getLeft() and getRight() before derefencing them, that your copy constructor does NOT copy these values (that would mean there are two Nodes that think they are at the same position in the tree) and that your destructor either asserts if the node is not unlinked or unlinks the node.